# please tell me which one is faster desktop application or web application in .net

Tags: .net, multithreading, download

i am to create a application which will send an xml file through https protocol and get a xml file as a response. and this process will go for more then lac. times(continusly to download all xml files around 1-2 lac.). so please tell me i should create a desktop application for this (in .net) or asp.net . and should i use threading for this otherwise i think application will be hang..and i would not be able to see the current status..

Comment: To clarify: 1 lac = 0.1 million.

Comment: As Tarydon said, yes. Still, never heard of it, so thanks for the clarification.

Comment: It seems that "lac" or "lakh" is from the Indian numbering system - on a global site like Stack Overflow it's worth sticking to more widely understood terms.

Comment: Yeah...google doesn't even seem to know what a lac is. Seriously, where does that come from?

Comment: Haai.. please give me solution..

Comment: its very simple.. lots of continus more then 100000 request and response in xml format through https protocol.. so what to use..desktop or web application.

Comment: @Dot Net Developer: No, it's not that simple. You haven't given any idea how long these take, whether any user input is required, whether it should run as an unattended service, etc.

Comment: i will run unattended... mins i will set source xml and i will be continusly sent and received..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is going to do something continuously in the background, you may well want it to be a Windows service in the first place. If you need to display the results of the processing, you could get the service to write them somewhere that a desktop or web app has access to them.

Where would the web application be hosted, if you went that route? Would it have a better network connection than wherever the desktop application would be running? Depending on exactly what you're doing, that may have performance implications.

If you need to do this operation to several servers or with several files at once then you may well want to use multiple threads - but if it's just a case of making a request, dealing with the response, making another request etc then it may not be necessary or useful to do so in the service approach. You'd need to be careful that you could write the results out in a way that they could be read at the same time by the desktop or web app without having to block.

Beyond this, we really need more information about what you're trying to do - it's all a bit vague at the moment.

Comment: yes its as u said "just a case of making a request, dealing with the response, making another request .".. please tell me why window service? why not window application?

Comment: even you can make some other background application because this is not always very easy to work with windows service.

Comment: @Dot Net Developer: It *sounds* like this is something which should be continuously running in the background - which is why a windows service sounds appropriate. However, if you can give us more information about what will be done with the data, we may be able to advise you better.

Comment: @Pankaj: If you want a process to run unattended, that's what services are designed for. Why do you think services exist in the first place?

Comment: @Downvoter: Care to explain the downvote? Which part do you disagree with?

Answer (score 0):

Well definitly desktop application is more faster than web based application.

But more depends upon the context in which your application will be running.Yo can make web based application more responsive my making use of web methods(web services).

One more thing I can think of is desktop application can make use of system resources more effectivly than a web based application.

Comment: See my response to Pankaj and the second paragraph of my answer: there are times when web applications will be faster than desktop applications, so I reject your first assertion. I'd also question how you think web services make web applications more responsive - were you actually thinking of Ajax instead?

Comment: @Jon: Yes , I was speaking about Ajax.More and more ajax based frameworks are coming up and along with their support for JSON the quest for making webpages more responsive is on the rise.

But like you mentioned application which you need to run for longer period of time or say which needs to run in background(scheduler , service) etc have to be implemented in local machine to be as effective as possible.Web application can target large audience but providing optimal performance to every individual is dependent on various factors.Getting best of both world is a challenging task.

Answer (score -1):

Please describe your functionality in detail.Desktop application is always faster then web application if you are processing document's and mail them....

Comment: i need to download lots of xml files. for that i need to send a xml file to get a xml as response that this process will continue for 1-2 lac. times. so tell me which type of application should i create to perform such operation

Comment: @Pankaj: Really? Do you believe that a desktop application could search the web faster than one of the popular search engines, even if it had enough disk?

Comment: @@Jon we have some barriers with web application like data need to process,speed of internet etc.I am agree with you that web search is a good but not in all conditions.

Comment: @Pankaj: Desktop applications sit closer to the user; web applications often sit closer to the data. Which is "faster" in general will depend on exactly what you need to do. There are barriers with desktop applications too, which you seem to be ignoring - notably that you're restricted to the processing power of a desktop machine, instead of potentially a large data centre.

Comment: @@Jon i m agree with you, your vision so very clear about web and windows but in that condition user may have data which may hang the application.We still don't know the purpose of application . selection of web or windows is based on client requirement and resource he has.

Comment: I completely agree that it will depend on the details - I disagree with your assertion that desktop applications are *always* faster than web applications though.